# Flatten in Keras video answering machine example

Tags: keras

In Keras' video question answering example (https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), what does the `vision_model.add(Flatten())` at the end of the convolutional neural net do and why is it needed?

Full source:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Embedding, Dense
from keras.models import Model, Sequential

# First, let's define a vision model using a Sequential model.
# This model will encode an image into a vector.
vision_model = Sequential()
vision_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
vision_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
vision_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
vision_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
vision_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
vision_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
vision_model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
vision_model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
vision_model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
vision_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
vision_model.add(Flatten())
```

Then later

```
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed

video_input = Input(shape=(100, 224, 224, 3))
# This is our video encoded via the previously trained vision_model (weights are reused)
encoded_frame_sequence = TimeDistributed(vision_model)(video_input)  # the output will be a sequence of vectors
encoded_video = LSTM(256)(encoded_frame_sequence)  # the output will be a vector
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running:

```
vision_model.summary()
```

we get:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 222, 222, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 111, 111, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 111, 111, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 109, 109, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 54, 54, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 54, 54, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 52, 52, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 50, 50, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 25, 25, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 160000)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,735,488
Trainable params: 1,735,488
Non-trainable params: 0
```

`vision_model.add(Flatten())` flattens `vision_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))` from (None, 25, 25, 256)  to (None, 160000)